Decorators work on Linux/Unix but not on Windows
I'm facing an issue with NestJS decorators when running in a Windows environment.
I have the following decorator:
export const customCommands: Function[] = [];

export function CustomCommand(target: Function) {
  fabreqCommands.push(target);
}

With this decorator, I'm able to mark one class as a CustomCommand:
@CustomCommand
export class CustomClass {}

With this decorator, I'm able, when spinning up a server, to bind custom commands to it:
@Injectable()
export class BootstrappingService {
  constructor(
    private readonly moduleRef: ModuleRef,
    private readonly logger: LoggerService,
    private readonly commandMapper: CommandMapperService,
  ) {
    this.logger.setCurrentContext(BootstrappingService.name);
  }

  bindCommandsToMicroservice(): void {
    console.log({ customCommands });
    if (!process.env.COMMANDS_LIST) {
      return this.bindCommands(customCommands);
    }

    const selectedCommands = process.env.COMMANDS_LIST.split(',');
    const commandsToBind = customCommands.filter((command) => {
      return selectedCommands.includes(command.prototype.commandName);
    });

    return this.bindCommands(commandsToBind);
  }

  bindCommands(commands: Function[]) {
    commands.forEach((commandFound) => {
      const reference = this.moduleRef.get(commandFound, { strict: false });
      const commandName = commandFound.prototype.name;

      this.commandMapper.mapper.set(commandName, reference);
      this.logger.log(`Command "${commandName}" bound to microservice.`);
    });
  }
}

This piece of code comes from a library I've created that, once injects it, runs this command discovery process and attach them to the server. This discovery process is registering commands by searching them into folders and discovering which ones we want to import, on the CommandModule.registerCommandsAsync() method we are seeing below:
@Module({
  imports: [
    CommandDiscoveryModule,
    CommandModule.registerCommandsAsync()
  ],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(private readonly boostrap: BootstrappingService) {}

  async onModuleInit() {
    await this.boostrap.bindCommandsToMicroservice();
  }
}

============

import { AppModule as CustomModule } from '@my-library/modules/app';

@Module({
  imports: [CustomModule]
})
export class AppModule {}

Beautiful. Works like a charm. However, it is not working on Windows environments. If I run it on Linux/Unix, the console.log instruction I have at the beginning of the method just brings back all classes that contain the CustomCommand decorator. On Windows though, it does not happen. It just brings an empty array and, whenever it finishes all NestJS bindings, then the customCommands array is ready with its data within.
Do you guys have an idea of why that could be happening?
Thank you all!
